# RPM - modifying the package after signing

Tags: linux, package, rpm, signature, sign

We use RPM packages in order to deploy our product in our customers' environments. In order to make the RPM fully self-contained, we 'personalize' the RPM to suit the specific customer's environment. This way, the customer only needs to install the RPM without following any wizard to editing configuration files.

My problem is as follows:
We sign the RPM package before personalizing it. The personalization process involves appending information to the RPM file (without really adding RPM headers, simply appending raw data). This modification (naturally) breaks the signature of the package.

What I'm looking for is a trick to let me modify the file without breaking the signature.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. The 'lead' part of the package contains reserved bytes which can be used, but it is very limited in size and not scalable.
2. Adding extended file attributes - very easy to use but the attributes disappear when copying the file (there are special flags to retain the attributes, but we can't enforce their usage).
3. We thought of inserting a dummy header to the RPM and to trick the RPM code into not checking it, still not sure how to do that.
4. Signing the package AFTER the personalization has taken place - also not scalable because it means we need to sign the package for each customer instead of just once.

Note that I'm know that a signature should prevent modifying the contents of a file (it behaves as expected). Yet, I don't really want to modify the RPM **data**, just include extra info in the file.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To whoever downvoted my question -  it's really not constructive to just downvote without giving any justification. Does my question give the impression that no research was done prior to asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really MUST modify a *.rpm while preserving existing signatures, then add tags to the signature header, preferably with tag numbers between decimal ~275 to 999. Both existing signature plaintexts (header-only and header+payload) will no be affected by additional tags/data in the signature header.

Note that more recent versions of RPM have been forced to explicitly enumerate tags and types and data in order to prevent segfaults discovered by fuzzing. But even in that case, there is a padding tag (0x3fffffff from memory) that can be populated with additional data. Again -- iirc -- the latest versions of rpm also verify that the padding is all 0x00 so caveat emptor.

Meanwhile you have not described what "personalization" is, and any tags added to the signature header will be discarded when the package is installed. Note also that the code to rewrite a signature header in a *.rpm is a bit tricky because of padding to ensure that the metadata header that follows a signature header is 8byte aligned.

I suggest that you will find that an additional file containing "personalization" is a better engineering approach. The art of hacking is knowing when to stop ;-)

Comment: I'd certainly prefer using a separate file for configuration... it is way cleaner  . It just conflicts with the way our product works today on other OS's, so I was strongly encouraged to keep it this way. Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll look into it (+1 from me)

Comment: If I may ask, how do you add a tag to the signature header? I didn't find any tool for that. Should I write a proprietary code for that?

Comment: There isn't a tool, but there is an RPM API for loading/unloading headers and adding/deleting tags. Its not very complicated coding. There is no tool because there is little need to extend *.rpm packages without resigning.

Answer (score 3):

The 5th choice would be to make a package which incorporates your changes and depends upon the signed package.  Whether you sign *your* package of course depends upon how it is distributed.

If your package modifies files in the original RPM, you can work around this (conflicting use of filenames) by making the `%pre` and `%preun` scriptlets rename the original files to a backup version and adding a symbolic link to your replacements.  That does interfere with verifying the original package contents, but your modifications should be something that you can verify on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand you correctly, you mean creating an additional RPM package and to distribute it as well. However I would like to use a single file. I don't need to modify any packed file, BTW.

Comment: This answer is the way to do it. You don't repackage the `httpd` RPM from the OS vendor, because then you are in the security patch business. You create an RPM named something like `httpd-config-myorg` that `Requires` `httpd` and drops in the config files. If the other RPM doesn't flag config files properly, you use `%pre`, `%post`, and `%triggerin` as noted above.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what about the 'httpd-config-myorg' package? Don't you need to sign it as well? If you do, then, again, you'll have to repeat signing procedure for each customer.

Comment: Noted in "your modifications should be something that you can verify on a case-by-case basis."   If the packages have to be signed, you would have to sign yours, and you **cannot** add your content to someone else's signature.

Answer (score 1):

> Signing the package AFTER the personalization has taken place - also
>   not scalable because it means we need to sign the package for each
>   customer instead of just once.

Why this does not scale? Just because rpmsign want you to enter passphrase? Look on obs-sign
https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Signer
(available in Suse, Fedora and Epel). It is able to automate the signing and yet keep it secure.

Comment: No, because the signing process is not fully automated. Plus, the entity that adds the personalization (and holds the customers' data) currently doesn't have the ability to sign (it has no access to the private key). Thanks for the link, I'll have a look (+1)

Comment: With obs-sign the private key is (can be) stored on different machine, where you have no access. You just compute the digest on the client, you send it to signing server (it check for whitelisted IP) and it send back the signature, which client inject into RPM header. You can retrieve the public key, but private key never leave the signing server.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How do you inject the digest into the RPM? Is there a built in command for that? (like rpm --addsign?)

Comment: The binary /usr/bin/sign (written in C) will do that for you. It will talk to /usr/sbin/signd (written in Perl) on server. It will compute the digest and inject the retrieved signature into rpm file.